# Can we have 1000 operations contracts in one service contract in a WCF service

Tags: wcf

Please can any one tell me that we can have 1000 operation contracts in one service contract in a WCF service. Does it affect maintenance when we make changes to these operations contracts?

Comment: You might want to tell us why you want to do this.

Comment: OMG, 1000 operations? Who is going to write that?

Answer (score 4):

**Brief version**: yes, theoretically and technically, you could - but that doesn't mean that you should..... the recommended number of operations on a service contract should not exceed 7 to 10, in any best practice recommendation I know....

**Extended version:**

I'm not saying that'll be a very easy to use and easy to understand service with that many operations. And yes - a service with 1000 operations is much more likely to change, so you'll probably have more frequent updates and thus need to come up with a really good versioning strategy.

You might also want to have a look at the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) - a principle of object-oriented design. One class (like your service here) should always have one responsibility and one only - I highly doubt you'll have 1000 methods that all deal with the same responsibility.....

Comment: @neslekkiM: just trying to say: yes, you (theoretically, technically) could - but that doesn't mean you should ....

Answer (score 3):

It would be much easier if someone just said "No, you can't" :-P